# ¿What is the proper translation for the linguistic term "WORD FORMS" into Spanish?

Tags: terminología, traducción

The translations for the linguistic term "WORD FORMS" in Google Translate and PONS.EU into Spanish are more or less the same "Formas de Palabras", but this translation doesn't seem to have the same sense that it has in English (See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morphology_%28linguistics%29#Lexemes_and_word_forms) for an explanation and definition of this term).

Comment: _Word-form_ is one of [the three meanings of "word"](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/pdf-files/threekindsofword.pdf) in English; it may or may not have such a fixed technical status in Spanish, where one can identify and speak of _radical, terminación, desinencia_, and _tema_ for almost every word.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In linguistics we normally call *lema* the headword of a word (that is, the way we would find it in a dictionary: its form in singular/masculine/infinitive). All the inflections of a lemma (plurals, conjugated verbs, etc) are called *formas*.

So dog would be a **lema**, and its **formas** (word forms) would be *dog* and *dogs*.

Answer (score 4):

Probably the easiest way to answer a question like this, is simply to read the [Spanish version](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morfolog%C3%ADa_ling%C3%BC%C3%ADstica#Lexemas_.28Morfemas_l.C3.A9xicos.29) of the wiki page you linked in your question. Based on that, I believe the answer you seek is:

> [Morfemas léxicos](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morfolog%C3%ADa_ling%C3%BC%C3%ADstica#Lexemas_.28Morfemas_l.C3.A9xicos.29)